# How to link a C project with a C++ static library(using opencv) in eclipse

Tags: c++, c, eclipse, opencv, static

I have created a c++ static library in eclipse which is using *opencv*.It is build fine and I want to include it in another c project in the same workspace.

**Trying with**

1)I have included library path in properties->c/c++ build->setting ->GCC C compiler ->Includes ->"*path of project*".

2)properties->c/c++ build->setting ->GCC C Linker-> Libraries ->Liraries(-i)->"*Name of Lib*"
3).properties->c/c++ build->setting ->GCC C Linker-> Libraries ->Liraries(-i)->"*path of Lib*"

But,this is not working while running the c project cannot find the static library functions giving error -"UNDEFINED REFERENCE TO THE FUNCTION"

Suggest a way to solve the problem.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Generally speaking, you have to provide an interface to your library that can be called from C. That means C-style functions, not C++ functions. And then you have to make sure that the C compiler and the C++ compiler agree on the names that those functions get when the code is compiled; read about `extern "C"` for that.

Comment: Thanks Pete,I am already using extern "C" in the function declaration.I have checked the code with visual studio on windows and it is working fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the answer.

These are the files needed to include
"${workspace_loc:/staticLibrary}"
MSDK/include
/IPP_Legacy/x64/include
Levmar/x64/include
/opencv/lib
opengl/x64/include/GL
Tesseract/x64/include/tesseract
freeGLUT/x64/include/GL
/ffmpeg/x64/include/libavcodec
compilers_and_libraries_2016.3.210/linux/ipp/include
compilers_and_libraries_2016.3.210/linux/mkl/include
compilers_and_libraries_2016.3.210/linux/tbb/include
compilers_and_libraries_2016.3.210/linux/daal/include

After these inclusion I faced a error of
 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6: error adding symbols: DSO missing from command line
for which I got help from the link
http://i0.wp.com/omtlab.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/07/4.png

now the program is working all fine
Thank you